# Smooth scroll to position without downloading all items every time

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, smooth-scrolling

I am building a photo sharing app with a feed similar to Instagram. The main feed fragment consists of two different feeds in a view pager (recent and following) and then there are two other fragments at the same level as the main feed fragment (profile and settings).

I would like both feed states to be kept when navigating through the app. Currently, if you swipe between the two feeds in the view pager their state is saved at the current position, but if navigating to profile or settings, the feed is back to the beginning when returning.

I am able to save the last item on both using a shared view model (I found that to be the easiest way). My problem is scrolling back to the position when returning.
At first, I've just tried a simple scroll to the position but that didn't work and I believe it is because I tried to call it before the recycler was populated.

What I am wondering about is though, is there a way for me to keep the recycler populated when navigating to other fragments? I am worried about the data consumption of my app. If I need to repopulate what might be hundreds of already scrolled through photos in two different feeds, every time the user jumps between fragments, that would take a lot of data from the user.

I'd appreciate any tips and ideas, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to go about. One is you can keep the recycler view populated even after navigating to other fragments. You can do that by setting off screen page limit of your `ViewPager`. Limit parameter is the number of pages that should be retained to either side of the current page in the view hierarchy in an idle state.

```
ViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3) // in this case 3 fragments on either side of the current page will be retained.
```

As you said, it might take lot of memory.

Another way is where you post the scrolling code in the main thread, so that your recycler view will get enough time to initialize and populate the items.

Do following after you have set data in your recycler view adapter

```
recyclerView.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Call your scrolling code  
        recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(adapter.getItemCount() - 1);                                 
    }
});
```